# How to remove query string from Firebase Storage download URL

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

**Problem:**

I need to be able to remove all link decoration from the download URL that is generated for images in Firebase Storage. 
However, when all link decoration is stripped away, the resulting link currently would return a JSON document of the image's metadata.

**Context:**

The flow goes as follows:

An image is uploaded to Firebase from an iOS app. Once that is done the download URL is then sent in a POST request to an external server.

The server that the URL is being sent to doesn't accept link decoration when submitting image URLs.

**Goal:**

Alter the Firebase Storage download URL such as it is stripped of all link decoration like so:

- https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/[FOLDER_NAME]%[IMAGE_NAME].jpg

**Notes:**

The problem is twofold really, first the link needs to be manipulated to remove all the link decoration. Then the behavior of the link needs to changed, since in order to return an image, you need ?alt=media following the file extension, in this case .jpg. Currently, without link decoration, using the link with my desired structure would return a JSON document of the metadata.

The current link structure is as follows:

- https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/[FOLDER_NAME]%[IMAGE_NAME].jpg?alt=media&token=[TOKEN]

Desired link structure:

- https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/[FOLDER_NAME]%[IMAGE_NAME].jpg

The token is necessary for accessing the image depending security rules in place, but can be ignored with the proper read permissions. I can adjust the rules as needed, but I still need to be able to remove the ?alt=media and still return an image.

Comment: So you want to get just folder_name and image_name from the returned url?

Comment: Or you just want to remove the query string (`?alt=medi&token=[TOKEN]`)?

Comment: I want to remove the query string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building up on Frank's answer, if you access to your associated Google Cloud Platform project, find the bucket in the Storage tab and make this bucket public, you will be able to get the image from here with the format you wish. That is, you will not be accessing through Firebase

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/[FOLDER_NAME]%[IMAGE_NAME].jpg`

but through Google Cloud Storage, with a link like

`https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket_name]/[path_to_image]`

Once in your GCP project Console, access the Storage bucket with the same name as the one you have in your Firebase project. They are the same bucket. Then make the bucket public by following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets). After that, you will be able to construct your links as mentioned above and they will be accessible with no token and no `alt=media` param. If you do not want to make the public to everyone, you will be able to play around with the permissions there as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, I found the link I need in the console. Next step: Have the iOS app access the download link from GCP

Comment: What do you mean by 'Have the iOS app access the download link from GCP'? If the content is in the same bucket, you only need to know the name of the file. The rest of the URL is always the same, and same way you mentioned in your question, but using the structure mentioned above. If there is something else now related to iOS, perhaps you should open a different thread. If this answer worked for you to solve the main issue posted (obtain the download URL for an image uploaded to a bucket), accepting the answer would help other users with the same issue to find this thread more easily =)

Comment: Yeah sorry, i figured that out after I commented.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the url string into two halves by using `String.componentsSeparatedByString(_ separator:)`

```swift
Storage.storage().reference().child(filePath).downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
    let urlString = url.absoluteString
    let urlStringWithoutQueryString = urlString.componentsSeparatedByString("?").first!
})
```

Calling `.downloadURL` on a `StorageReference` will return you that URL, but this method can be used to remove the query string from any URL. `String.componentsSeparatedByString(_ separator:)` breaks a `String` into an array of `String`s, splitting the string by any occurrence of a given separator, in this case `?`.

**NOTE** this method assumes that `?` occurs only once within the url string, which I believe is the case for all Firebase Storage urls.

Comment: I'll give that a shot!

Comment: So that does resolve the issue of removing the query string, however the new link returns the JSON metadata document instead of the actual image.

Comment: You need the token to get the image

Comment: From my understanding you need alt=media to get the image

Comment: Yup, I just added ?alt=media to the stripped url and it returned the image

Comment: Interesting, I'm testing on my own Firebase Storage images and I get json along the lines of `{"error": {"code": 403,"message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"}}`
when I don't pass the token.

Comment: You could use this `let urlStringWithoutQueryString = urlString.componentsSeparatedByString("&token=").first!` instead of `let urlStringWithoutQueryString = urlString.componentsSeparatedByString("?").first!` then.

Comment: The token is required depending on your security rules. If you allow public read access to the object or the bucket you don't need a token

Comment: So the problem still lies in that the shortened link doesn't actually download the photo. I just get JSON of the various metadata I attached to the photo

Comment: There won't be a way for the shortened link to get you the image. I believe you will at least need the `?alt=media`

Comment: Thats the kicker aint it. The server im sending to wont even read the query parameters so i need to change the behavior of the actual link

Comment: Is the url you're sending escaped for URL? The issue is probably that you need to percent escape the string you're sending to the server.

Comment: I imagine the `?` is giving you issues? Some characters in your url need to be escaped. Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: When uploading to the server, you could encode the string by using something like `urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!`

Comment: Its not the percent escape, I asked the devs of the server myself and they confirmed i need to remove the query params

Comment: If you ask them why, we could maybe figure out a fix. They should really be able to accept percent encoded urls. Especially considering they are required for images to even be stored.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to resolve the issue on my end

Comment: You may need to use a third party asset storage service, though I imagine almost all of them will require a query string. Its very odd that their back end cannot handle percent encoded urls.

Comment: I was considering using an S3 bucket, I've already tested that would work. But it seems like a very resource intensive solution

Comment: @AIsrafil I have seen that AWS stored images and videos sometimes end with a .jpg or .mp4, which is what I'm looking for. I have an API asking for an image file or mp4 file as input, but this seems impossible to do with firebase stored items

Comment: @AIsrafil Did you end up using an S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

You should treat the download URL that you get back from Firebase as an opaque string. There's no way to strip the parameters from a download URL without breaking that download URL.

If you want to allow public access to the files in your bucket with simpler URLs, consider [making the object in your (or even your entire) bucket public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

Comment: Even if I made the bucket or the object public wouldn't I still need alt=media to return the actual image?